# HDMI Monitor Not Detected On Boot

Tags: hdmi

This doesn't involve a secondary monitor. It's the primary, and only, monitor on my system.

It's an HDMI monitor, and it's not being detected by Ubuntu, at any point in the boot cycle.

Comment: Sigh. Never mind. The cable apparently failed! "Always check the cables :("